# ¿Como hacer un arreglo bidimensional de String en C#?

Tags: c#, array, string, bucle-for

tengo un pequeño problema, espero y me puedan apoyar;

El problema es que quiero hacer un arreglo de 2 dimensiones para hacer una tabla , algo como esto:

```
                    string[][] dat = new string[][]
                {
                    new string[] {"Tienda"     ,"Existencias"},
                    new string[] {"Argentina","1"},
                    new string[] {"México","5"},
                    new string[] {"Brazil","9"},
                    new string[] {"Canada","2"}

                };
```

como ven son 2 columnas y varias filas, las columnas siempre van a ser 2 pero las filas pueden variar.

Para estar moviendo los indices del arreglo y y estar llenándolos con un `for`,
este es el código que tengo e intente pero solo se guarda el ultimo elemento que da verdadero en el `if`;

```
Store[] tienda = p_item;
for (int c = 0; c < tienda.Length; c++)
        {
            if (tienda[c].stockOnHand > 0)
            {
                string[][] dat = new string[][]
                {
                    new string[] {tienda[c].storeName ,tienda[c].stockOnHand.ToString()}
                };

                v_dataTable = dat;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

Intente poniendo una variable que fuera aumentando, pero me muestra un error: "Error    1   A constant value is expected"

```
string[][] dat = new string[][]
                {
                    new string[numero] {tienda[c].storeName ,tienda[c].stockOnHand.ToString()}

                };
                numero++;
```

¿Hay alguna forma de hacer algo parecido a esto?

```
String[][] dat = new String[][];
dat[c][1]={"tienda[c].storeName ,tienda[c].stockOnHand.ToString()"};
```

De ir llenando las posiciones de acuerdo a la posición del arreglo e ir haciendo la tabla.

¿Tienen alguna otra idea de como ir llenando ese arreglo?

Comment: amigo, tienes que manejar dos intrucciones for, uno para recorrer las columnas y otro para recorrer las filas, en el codigo que pones solo estas manejando un for, por lo cual no te va a resultar, o segun yo no, a lo mejor te sirve este ejemplo de aqui: https://andresmtzg.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/ejemplo-arreglo-bidimensional.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Al menos la primer dimension deberia indicarla, algo como esto

```
Store[] tienda = p_item;

string[][] dat = new string[tienda.Length][];

for (int c = 0; c < tienda.Length; c++)
{
    if (tienda[c].stockOnHand > 0)
    {
        dat[c] = new string[] {tienda[c].storeName ,tienda[c].stockOnHand.ToString()}
    }

}
```

analiza la documentacion de como se trabaja este tipo de array

[Jagged Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays)

Pero la verdad no recomendaria uses este tipo de array, usa listas y clases, o sea define

```
public class Tienda
{
    public string storeName {get;set;}
    public string stockOnHand {get;set;}
}
```

y luego usas linq

```
List<Tienda> dat = p_item.Where(x=>x.stockOnHand > 0)
                        .Select(new Tienda()
                        {
                            storeName = x.storeName,
                            stockOnHand = x.stockOnHand.ToString()
                        }});
```

asi de facil, tienes una lista que seran las rows y la entidad `Tienda` tiene las dos propiedades que sera las columnas

Answer (score -1):

Ya encontré como solucionarlo y es que se utilizaba una clase para hacer la tabla pero decidí hacerla directo y así fue como funcionó, les dejo como quedo por si le sirve a alguien

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Tienda", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Existencias", typeof(string));

        for (int c = 0; c < tienda.Length; c++)
        {
            if (tienda[c].stockOnHand > 0)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { tienda[c].storeName, tienda[c].stockOnHand.ToString()});
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }ódigo aquí
```